# csh list of commands like ksh { list; }

Tags: bash, ksh, csh, tcsh, sh

In bourne-compatible shells, the `{ list; }` syntax causes the complete list of commands to be read by the shell before executing it, without opening a new shell. Is there anything similar for the csh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dennis says, no direct equivalent.  'eval' might be woth looking at - depends what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think `csh` only has parentheses. But they create a subshell (in addition to grouping commands) just like they do in Bourne-style shells.